# Infura tutorial no longer accurate, how to get the initial curl HTTPS POST to work?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, infura, command-line, tutorials

Following the guide at https://blog.infura.io/getting-started-with-infura-28e41844cc89, step 2 after registering is to send a HTTPS POST using curl. The command is

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1}' https://mainnet.infura.io/MYAPIKEY
```

But when I try this (with my actual API key in place in the url) I get an error

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion"," ...
+      ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I am using windows 10 powershell and have downloaded curl-7.60.0-win64-mingw, which I ran by running the curl.exe in the bin folder.

According to another answer on stackoverflow that recommended using the command

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```

on windows 10 to avoid that specific Invoke-WebRequest error, and then running the curl command. When I do this I get no error, but nothing happens. There is no JSON returned with the Client and version, like the tutorial says their should be.

How do I get this to work? I can't follow the tutorial with these problems.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1):

just run on my shell, it return correct result.

```
    $ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1}' https://mainnet.infura.io
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"Geth/v1.8.15-omnibus-255989da/linux-amd64/go1.10.1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK, but infura  must have overspent on designing the frontend to their site because symbols for the CLI have been replaced with prettier ones!

`”` should be `"`

`‘` should be `'`

`—` should be `--`